# git line-endings issue with just one clone of a repo

Tags: git, github, line-endings, newline, git-diff

Ok, I have a git repo. All clones running same-ish version of git (pretty much latest).

- 'origin' is on GitHub.com
- clones on various CentOS servers, no problems with line-endings encountered
- clone on my Mac OS system (using git via cmd line, and/or Tower GUI), no problems with line-endings either..

BUT

- another clone on a Ubuntu server, git-diff thinks the entire file has changed when I make any changes to a file

So, what must I do with git-config on this one Ubuntu box to sort the problem? I've read various articles (and git-config docs) on the subject, but it's not entirely clear what the decisive one-hit fix is.. ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to turn `core.autocrlf` off.

Comment: Is core.autocrlf on by default then? ..because i've not turned it on. Also, once I get the crlf config right, would I need to re-checkout my entire working copy with 'git checkout HEAD' before making further changes to the files?

Comment: I don't know if it's on by default on Ubuntu, but the only reason I can see why the crlf would change is that it is on. As for whether you need to check out again, I would guess you would, but `git status` will tell you that.

Comment: Ok, I don't have any git-config directives set either globally or for this repo itself. 'git config list' returns nothing. So it must be to do with how the OS is dealing with the line-endings. Any ideas how to work around this? BTW to edit the files, I'm opening them over FTP and editing with TextMate on Mac, then saving back via FTP.

Comment: oh, that FTP bit may be an important detail: do any of the files that you don't download and re-upload over FTP have every line change? Do you transfer the files in binary (image) mode?

Comment: I have TextMate set with its default preference of using LF only for line-endings, even on existing files, not just new ones it creates. Perhaps I need to remove the 'even on existing files' preference ?!

Comment: did you check whether the only files that had the problem were the ones you downloaded and re-uploaded over FTP? That'll at least tell you whether you're looking in the right direction

Comment: You're right, the snag is with either the FTPing or TextMate. If I edit a file from the command line (with pico) on the box, no worries. But editing in TextMate via FTP changes the line-endings, even if I untick the preference to apply TM's line-endings scheme to existing files.

Comment: Question is, can I set some config in git so git won't care about the changed line-endings?

Comment: Aha, I seem to have solved the problem by doing the opposite - turning core.autocrlf ON ;) 'git config --global core.autocrlf true'